# How to give border a single border for two adjacent cells in css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am making a form in html, and I am using a table for layout of my input controls and labels.

For each input of a form, there is one label associated with it.

I want a border to appear around each pair of adjacent cell that is a label and its associated input tag.

I tried making a div around the two adjacent `<td>` tags but it says "invalid tag" as only `<td>` are allowed inside  a `<tr>` tag.

Is there anyway to do it either in CSS or anything else ?

My HTML sample code :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Below is a screenshot of what I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Can you post HTML please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could apply classes to your td's you could try this:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Label1: </td>
        <td>input1</td>
        <td class="label">Label2: </td>
        <td>input2</td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

With the following css:

```
table {
    background-color: silver;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0px;
}

td.label {
    border-width: 1px 0px 1px 1px;    
}
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/H3p8e/2/

Answer (score 4):

You've not `collapsed` your `table border`, try this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JLgSL/)

```
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td {
   border: 1px solid #c00000;
}
```

Comment: I want it around two `<td>` cells not each one

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply `border-collapse:collapse;` rule.